# Displaying detailed #error informations SSRS report without using BIDS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

How can i get any informations about #error that occured in cell without debugging it localy in BIDS? Is there any possibility to show error message inside report? I haven't found anything usefull on google related to #error in cell.
Im interested only in cell #error, of properly generated report...

Answer (score 3):

Run the report from VS by pushing F5 or Debug->Start Debugging. The expression errors will be written out in the Output window.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the info from the usual VB handler. You'll have to write your own handlers to get this.

For example, you could write either custom code embedded in the report, or better, a custom assembly, that returns a string for your cell's value. This code would need to perform all the work that might be returning the #error in your current function. But the code could check for problems or catch exceptions and still return a valid string. You could put your own error messages in this string. (That's why I like the assembly: there you could easily catch all exceptions and still return a string. I know C# better than VB.)

So not too easy, but if you are comfortable with coding, not a big stretch.